# Can only read one temperature reading from the processor of the sensor, for other sensors it does not work

Tags: c#

Only one reading can be taken from a sensor at a time. I used the concept of asynchronous sockets, that is, it is only reading the processor temperature of a single sensor at a time. When you add more, it shows that there is an error. Any ideas would be appreciated.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.IO.Ports;

namespace SmartLynx
{
    public class RepeatableTemperatureMeasurementJob : RepeatableMeasurementJob
    {        
        //general
        public temperatureGauge TempDevice;

        //udp
        UdpClient socketCmd;
        UdpClient socketCmdText;
        private const int cmdTextPort = 6666;
        private const int cmdPort = 6676;
        private double tempSensTop = 0;
        private double tempSensBottom = 0;
        private double tempProcessor = 0;
        private String firmware = "";
        private String streamType = "";
        private String camIP = "";

        //GMH3700
        //private CommunicatorSerial ComPort;
        private SerialPort PortGMH3700 = new SerialPort();
        public string ComPortbyUser { get; set; }
        public int DecimalAddress { get; set; }

        public RepeatableTemperatureMeasurementJob(bool _jobActive, string _jobName, int _neededSubJob) :base(_jobActive, _jobName, _neededSubJob)
        {
        }

        public override void initializeJob()
        {
            try
            {
                if (TempDevice == temperatureGauge.udp)
                {
                    camIP = parameters[0];
                    socketCmdText = new UdpClient(cmdTextPort);
                    socketCmdText.BeginReceive(new AsyncCallback(OnUdpDataCmdText), socketCmdText);
                    socketCmd = new UdpClient(cmdPort);
                    socketCmd.BeginReceive(new AsyncCallback(OnUdpDataCmd), socketCmd);
                }
                if (TempDevice == temperatureGauge.GMH3700)
                {
                    PortGMH3700.PortName = ComPortbyUser;
                    PortGMH3700.BaudRate = 4800; /* Baudrate '4800' oder '38400' */
                    PortGMH3700.Parity = Parity.None;
                    PortGMH3700.DataBits = 8;
                    PortGMH3700.StopBits = StopBits.One;
                    PortGMH3700.DtrEnable = true;
                    PortGMH3700.RtsEnable = false;
                    PortGMH3700.Open();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error TemperatureMesurement-Job initialization " + jobName + " : " + e.Message);
            }
        }

        public override void deinitializeJob()
        {
            try
            {
                if (TempDevice == temperatureGauge.udp)
                {
                    //socketCmd.Close();
                    //socketCmdText.Close();
                }
                if (TempDevice == temperatureGauge.GMH3700)
                {
                    PortGMH3700.Close();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error TemperatureMesurement-Job deinitialization " + jobName + " : " + e.Message);
            }
        }

        protected override void doMeasurement()
        {
            if (TempDevice == temperatureGauge.udp)
            {
                tempSensTop = 0;
                tempSensBottom = 0;
                tempProcessor = 0;
                firmware = "";
                streamType = "";
                requestData();
            }

            if (TempDevice == temperatureGauge.GMH3700)
            {
                if (PortGMH3700.IsOpen)
                {
                    byte AdressByte = Convert.ToByte(0xFF - Convert.ToByte(DecimalAddress));
                    byte Aufrufcode = 0x00;
                    byte bytestosendwithCRC = CRC(AdressByte, Aufrufcode);
                    byte[] MessageToSend = { AdressByte, Aufrufcode, bytestosendwithCRC };

                    PortGMH3700.Write(MessageToSend, 0, MessageToSend.Length);

                    Thread.Sleep(200); // Auf Nachricht warten

                    if (PortGMH3700.IsOpen && PortGMH3700.BytesToRead > 0)
                    {
                        int length = PortGMH3700.BytesToRead;
                        byte[] ComBuf = new byte[length];
                        PortGMH3700.Read(ComBuf, 0, length);

                        double outdblFloatWert;
                        Int16 outi16DezimalPunktPosition;
                        byte[] MessageByte = ComBuf;

                        try
                        {
                            Messwert32Decodieren(MessageByte[3], MessageByte[4], MessageByte[6], MessageByte[7], out outdblFloatWert, out outi16DezimalPunktPosition);
                            measuredValue = outdblFloatWert;
                            storeData();
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Error GMH3700: Received wrong message " + "(" + jobName + ")"); // 
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private void requestData()
        {
            try
            {
                IPAddress _camip = IPAddress.Parse(camIP);
                IPEndPoint _ep = new IPEndPoint(_camip, cmdTextPort);
                byte[] _sendbuf = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Cmd_ISL_GetCurrentSensorTemperature");
                socketCmdText.Send(_sendbuf, _sendbuf.Length, _ep);

                byte[] _sendbuf2 = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Get_Temp");
                socketCmdText.Send(_sendbuf2, _sendbuf2.Length, _ep);
                /*
                byte[] _sendbuf3 = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("APP_Version");
                socketCmdText.Send(_sendbuf3, _sendbuf3.Length, _ep);

                IPEndPoint _ep2 = new IPEndPoint(_camip, cmdPort);
                Byte[] _sendbuf4 = { 0x02, 0x00, 0x00, 0x10, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xED };
                socketCmd.Send(_sendbuf4, _sendbuf4.Length, _ep2);
                */
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error TemperatureMesurement-Job requestData " + jobName + " : " + e.Message);
            }
        }

        void OnUdpDataCmdText(IAsyncResult result)
        {
            try
            {
                // this is what had been passed into BeginReceive as the second parameter:
                UdpClient socket = result.AsyncState as UdpClient;
                // points towards whoever had sent the message:
                IPEndPoint source = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, cmdTextPort);
                // get the actual message and fill out the source:
                byte[] message = socket.EndReceive(result, ref source);
                // do what you'd like with `message` here:
                String s = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(message, 0, message.Length);
                String searchStringSensor = "Sensor Temp Top ";
                String searchStringProzessor = "Temp = ";
                String searchStringVersion = "Version : ";
                int startIndexSensor = s.IndexOf(searchStringSensor);
                int startIndexProzessor = s.IndexOf(searchStringProzessor);
                int startIndexVersion = s.IndexOf(searchStringVersion);
                if (camIP == source.Address.ToString())
                {
                    if (startIndexSensor == 0)
                    {
                        String[] substrings = s.Split(',');
                        String substringTop = substrings[0].Substring(16, substrings[0].Length - (4 + 16));
                        String substringBottom = substrings[1].Substring(8, substrings[1].Length - (9 + 4));
                        tempSensTop = Double.Parse(substringTop) / 100;
                        tempSensBottom = Double.Parse(substringBottom) / 100;
                        //measuredValue = tempSensTop;
                        //storeData();
                    }
                    else if (startIndexProzessor == 0)
                    {
                        String substringProzessor = s.Substring(7, s.Length - 12);
                        tempProcessor = Double.Parse(substringProzessor);
                        measuredValue = tempProcessor;
                        storeData();
                    }
                    else if (startIndexVersion > 0)
                    {
                        String substringVersion = s.Substring(18, s.Length - 18);
                        firmware = substringVersion;
                    }
                }
                // schedule the next receive operation once reading is done:
                socket.BeginReceive(new AsyncCallback(OnUdpDataCmdText), socket);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error TemperatureMesurement-Job OnUdpDataCmdTxt " + jobName + " : " + e.Message);
            }
        }

        void OnUdpDataCmd(IAsyncResult result)
        {
            try
            {
                // this is what had been passed into BeginReceive as the second parameter:
                UdpClient socket = result.AsyncState as UdpClient;
                // points towards whoever had sent the message:
                IPEndPoint source = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, cmdPort);
                // get the actual message and fill out the source:
                byte[] message = socket.EndReceive(result, ref source);
                // do what you'd like with `message` here:
                string[] receiveString = BitConverter.ToString(message).Split('-');

                if (camIP == source.Address.ToString())
                {
                    if (string.Concat(receiveString).Substring(0, 16) == "0201001001000002")
                    {
                        streamType = receiveString[8] + receiveString[9];
                    }
                }
                // schedule the next receive operation once reading is done:
                socket.BeginReceive(new AsyncCallback(OnUdpDataCmd), socket);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error TemperatureMesurement-Job OnUdpDataCmd " + jobName + " : " + e.Message);
            }
        }
        private byte CRC(byte inbyByte0, byte inbyByte1) // for GMH3700
        {
            byte byCRCByte = 0;
            UInt16 ui16Integer = (UInt16)((inbyByte0 << 8) | inbyByte1);
            for (UInt16 ui16Zaehler = 0; ui16Zaehler < 16; ui16Zaehler++)
            {
                if ((ui16Integer & 0x8000) == 0x8000)
                {
                    ui16Integer = (UInt16)((ui16Integer << 1) ^ 0x0700);
                }
                else
                {
                    ui16Integer = (UInt16)(ui16Integer << 1);
                }
            }
            byCRCByte = (byte)(255 - (ui16Integer >> 8));
            return byCRCByte;
        }

        /*2 Übertragungs-Bytes zu unsigned 16 Bit Integer zusammenfassen */
        private UInt16 UInt16Decodieren(byte inbyByteA, byte inbyByteB) // for GMH3700
        {
            return (UInt16)((UInt16)((255 - inbyByteA) << 8) | inbyByteB);
        }

        /*2 unsigned 16 Bit Integer zu unsigned32 Bit Integer zusammenfassen */
        private UInt32 UInt32Decodieren(UInt16 inui16Wert1, UInt16 inui16Wert2) // for GMH3700
        {
            return (UInt32)(inui16Wert1 << 16 | inui16Wert2);
        }

        /* 2Bytes aus Übertragung in Messwert oder Fehlercode umrechnen */
        private Int16 Messwert16Decodieren(byte inbyByte3, byte inbyByte4, out double outdblFloatWert, out Int16 outi16DezimalPunktPosition) // for GMH3700
        {
            UInt16 ui16Integer = UInt16Decodieren(inbyByte3, inbyByte4);
            outi16DezimalPunktPosition = (Int16)((ui16Integer & 0xC000) >> 14);
            ui16Integer = (UInt16)(ui16Integer & 0x3FFF);
            if ((ui16Integer >= 0x3FE0) && (ui16Integer <= 0x3FFF))
            {
                outdblFloatWert = (double)ui16Integer - (double)16352.0;
                return -36; /* Rückgabewert ist Fehlercode */
            }
            Int32 i32Nenner = (Int32)System.Math.Pow((double)10.0, (double)outi16DezimalPunktPosition);
            Int32 i32Zaehler = (Int32)((double)ui16Integer - (double)2048.0);
            outdblFloatWert = (double)((double)i32Zaehler / (double)i32Nenner);
            return 0; /* Rückgabewert ist kein Fehler, OK */
        }
        //
        bool CRCBerechnen(byte[] inByteArray, UInt16 inLaenge) // for GMH3700
        {
            if (inLaenge >= 3)
            {
                if (inByteArray[2] != CRC(inByteArray[0], inByteArray[1]))
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            if (inLaenge >= 6)
            {
                if (inByteArray[5] != CRC(inByteArray[3], inByteArray[4]))
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            if (inLaenge >= 9)
            {
                if (inByteArray[8] != CRC(inByteArray[6], inByteArray[7]))
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            if (inLaenge >= 12)
            {
                if (inByteArray[11] != CRC(inByteArray[9], inByteArray[10]))
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }

        /* 4 Bytes aus Übertragung in Messwert oder Fehlercode umrechnen */
        Int16 Messwert32Decodieren(byte inbyByte3, byte inbyByte4, byte inbyByte6, byte inbyByte7, out double outdblFloatWert, out Int16 outi16DezimalPunktPosition) // for GMH3700
        {
            outdblFloatWert = 0;
            outi16DezimalPunktPosition = 0;
            UInt16 ui16Integer1, ui16Integer2;
            ui16Integer1 = UInt16Decodieren(inbyByte3, inbyByte4);
            ui16Integer2 = UInt16Decodieren(inbyByte6, inbyByte7);
            UInt32 ui32Integer = UInt32Decodieren(ui16Integer1, ui16Integer2);
            /* Bytes zusammenfassen, mit Beispieldaten: 0x8DFFFFFC */
            outi16DezimalPunktPosition = (Int16)(((0xFF - inbyByte3) >> 3) - 15);
            /* Dezimalpunkt dekodieren, mit Beispieldaten: 0x0002*/
            ui32Integer = ui32Integer & 0x07FFFFFF;
            /* Rohwert dekodieren, mit Beispieldaten: 0x05FFFFFC */
            if ((100000000 + 0x2000000) > ui32Integer)
            {
                /* Daten sind gültige Werte */
                if (0x04000000 == (ui32Integer & 0x04000000))
                {
                    ui32Integer = (ui32Integer | 0xF8000000);
                    /* Mit Beispieldaten: 0xFDFFFFFC */
                }
                ui32Integer = (UInt32)((UInt64)ui32Integer + 0x02000000);
                /* Mit Beispieldaten: 0xFFFFFFFC */
            }
            else
            {
                /* Daten sind Fehlercodes, Fehlercode auscodieren */
                outdblFloatWert = (double)(ui32Integer - 0x02000000 - 16352.0);
                outi16DezimalPunktPosition = 0; return -36;
                /* Rückgabewert ist Fehlercode */
            }
            /* Umwandlung in Fliesspunkt Zahl, mit Beispieldaten: -4f */
            outdblFloatWert = (double)(Int32)ui32Integer;
            outdblFloatWert = outdblFloatWert / (Math.Pow(10.0f, (double)outi16DezimalPunktPosition));
            return 0; /* Rückgabewert ist OK, mit Beispieldaten: -0,04 */
        }

        public static byte[] combineByteArray(byte[] first, byte[] second) // for GMH3700
        {
            byte[] ret = new byte[first.Length + second.Length];
            Buffer.BlockCopy(first, 0, ret, 0, first.Length);
            Buffer.BlockCopy(second, 0, ret, first.Length, second.Length);
            return ret;
        }

        public byte[] addByteToByteArray(byte[] bArray, byte newByte) // for GMH3700
        {
            byte[] newArray = new byte[bArray.Length + 1];
            bArray.CopyTo(newArray, 0);
            newArray[newArray.Length - 1] = newByte;
            return newArray;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please create a *minimal*, complete, verfiable example. Also tell us what the exception (including the Exception class) is and wich exact line it happened on.

Comment: Sidenote: Exception handling is a pet-peeve of mine and your is bad. You catch exception - contuining after fatal exceptions - and only expose the message. Two cardinal sins of Exception handling. There are two articles on the mater that I link often and should get you up to speed: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/ | https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9538/Exception-Handling-Best-Practices-in-NET

Comment: removed duplicated explanation

Comment: After executing the jobs, all of the threads started successfully and then there was a problem in initializing for the 2nd sensor, displaying "Error TemperatureMesurement-Job initialization 4_cam2_temperature:Normally, each socket address (protocol, network address or connection) may only be used once"(refering to initializejob on the top )and then a problem in requestdata() for sensor 2 stating ""Error TemperatureMesurement-Job requestData 4_cam2_temperature:The object reference was not set to an object instance". The exception class used is Class System.exception.

Comment: continued...And only using temperatureGauge.udp not the temperatureGauge.GMH3700. It is only requesting the temperature from a particular sensor and not from others as seen in the ASCII code

Comment: I cant seem to find the error, it is communicating through the same UDP port it sends the request for the Temp for the first one but does not for the 2nd one. Any ideas would be apprerciated. Thanks and Regards